# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance when trying to filter the data with 'comment_id'

Tags: database, laravel, filtering

what i wants to do is to show the replies that are given to that particular comment on the post.Right now i am able to show the comment to that specific post but the replies are displayed along each comment.
here is the controller part of the code:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);
        $comments = Comment::where('blog_id', $id)->get()->all();
        $test = Comment::all();
//        $comments = Comment::whereIn('blog_id', $id)->get()->all();
        $commentReplies = CommentReply::where('comment_id'== $test->id)-
    >get();
//        $commentReplies = CommentReply::where('comment_id',$blog-
  >comment()->id)->get()->all();
        return 
view('admin/blog/front',compact('blog','comments','commentReplies'));
    }
```

i am saving the refrence to that comment in database in 'comment_id' but when i try to reach the 'comment_id' via $commentReplies it gives me the error of "**Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**"

Comment: I really recomend using a library called Fractal to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$commentReplies = CommentReply::whereIn('comment_id', $test->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

You also could use relationships. Define this one in the `Comment` model:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CommentReply::class);
}
```

Then load comments with replies:

```
$commentsWithReplies = Comment::with('replies')->get();
```

And to iterate over comments and replies:

```
@foreach ($commentsWithReplies as $comment)
    {{ $comment->text }}
    @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
        {{ $reply->text }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You also shouldn't chain `->get()->all()`, just use `->get()`.

And finally, the correct syntax for returning a view is (thanks to @Nikola Gavric):

```
return view('admin.blog.front', compact('blog', 'comments', 'commentReplies'))
```

Comment: Also he is failing at returning the view, it's not `return view('admin/blog/front')` but rather `return view('admin.blog.front')`

Comment: thanks for the solution @AlexeyMezenin actually i had the relationship in the Comment Model as an replies() but i was trying to reach the 'comment_id' through it :D
And it was giving me errors but what you told worked :)
once again thanks (y)

Comment: @NikolaGavric i was getting the view but the comment replies weren't working properly :) Thanks though